# 2 different classes A and B . variable is declared in class A .I want to get value of variable in B

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

```
class A
@i = 2
end

class B
puts @i
end
```

these are two classes in different files a.rb and b.rb. I want to print @i in class B. can anyone help me with that

Comment: Give it a try:
http://ruby-doc.org/docs/Tutorial/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how can i print the value of a variable of another class into other. what should i use require , load , include .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b.rb`:

```
require_relative 'a'

class B
  puts A.instance_variable_get(:@i)
end
```

Execute the file and you will get the output:

```
ruby b.rb
#=> 2
```

Comment: If this is the solution to your question please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to consider traditional way, before going for Ruby's black magic.

```
class A
  @i = 2
  def self.i
    @i
  end
end

class B
  puts A.i  #=> 2
end
```

If exposing `A`'s member is really unacceptable, then go for Andrey Deineko's solution.